# Neo4j Cypher GROUP BY and create a collection by conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

as the result of my current Neo4j Cypher query, I have the following rows with nodes:

```
WITH node, rootNode, resultNode
```

now, I need to transform this structure into the following:

1. `GROUP BY resultNode` (because `resultNode` may be duplicated)
2. For each `resultNode` group I need to create a collection which will contain nodes by the following formula:

   add `node` into collection `if node NOT EQUAL resultNode`

   add `rootNode` into collection `if rootNode NOT EQUAL resultNode`

so, as the result, I need to have something like this:

```
resultNode1, {node1, node2, ..., rootNode1, rootNode2...}
resultNode2, {node2...}
resultNode3, {}
resultNodeN, {nodeN..., rootNodeN}
...
```

Please help to construct such a query with Cypher

Comment: Need a bit more clarity on the problem you are solving. Look at the collect and reduce functions in cypher to aggregate results. The filtering is usually done before the aggreation but could occur after if the pattern it conducive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

1. For each `resultNode`, collect `node` and `rootNode` in a list.
2. Combine the lists of both `node` and `rootNode`.
3. From the final list, filter out all the nodes matching the `resultNode`.

Like this:

```
WITH resultNode, COLLECT(node) AS nodes, COLLECT(rootNode) AS rootNodes
WITH resultNode, apoc.coll.unionAll(nodes, rootNodes) AS allNodes
RETURN resultNode, [x IN allNodes WHERE x <> resultNode | x ] AS result
```

Update the condition in the `WHERE` clause accordingly.